# Why are spaces used to separate things in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is something in a wordpress stylesheet that I don't understand:

```
blockquote cite,
blockquote em,
blockquote i {
font-style: normal;
}
```

what does the space between blockquote and cite do? I understand if they are separated by a comma, then both blockquote and cite will have "font-style: normal;" now they are separated by space, does this mean if a blockquote tag is embedded into a cite tag it will get "font-style: normal;"?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The space is known as the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). `blockquote cite` selects any `cite` element within a `blockquote` element. Likewise for `blockquote em` and `blockquote i`.

In other words, it's not "if a blockquote tag is embedded into a cite tag", it's the other way around (besides, you can't place `blockquote`s in `cite`s in the first place).

As you note, commas group selector sequences into the same rule.

Answer (score 1):

This means target the `cite` tag inside the `blockquote` etc.

In this instance, the site is attempting to override all italics set inside a `blockquote`.

Comment: Well, not all, but plenty of common cases anyway :P

Answer (score 1):

A space between selectors will cause the style sheet to apply the rule selectively. A space is the descendant selector or combinator. It applies to *any* descendant element within the descender.

A rule of `blockquote cite { font-style: normal; }` would only apply the font style to both `item 1` **and** `item b`. Both `item 1` and `item b` are descendants of `item A`. `item A` will not get the rule.

```
 A. item A (Blockquote)
   1. item 1 (Cite)
     a. item a
     b. item b (Cite)
   2. item 2
```

This is slightly similar to the `>` selector. That is the child selector. It applies to any child of an element. A child is a 1st level descendant. In the table above with rule `blockquote > cite { font-style: normal; }` instead, `item b` would not get the font-style rule applied, as it is a 2nd level descendant, hence not a child. `item A` would also not get rule.

If you want both `blockquote` and any `cite` within `blockquote` to get the rule, they must both be listed:

`blockquote, blockquote cite { font-style: normal; }`