# I can not understand why it works css script, help me understand?

Tags: css

help me understand this code: 
**css**

```
nav ul ul{
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

**html**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2.3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">2.3.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2.3.2</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Question:**
Why become visible when you hover the mouse (2.3) elements "2.3.1 - 2.3.2" I guess that will become visible only elements 2.1 - 2.3 according to the line "nav ul li: hover> ul"?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is: when I hover 2.3 -> visible 2.3.1 ... Why? "nav ul li:hover > ul" it's an only ul-li-a-2.3 not 2.3.1... What I misunerstood?

Comment: `nav ul li:hover > ul` says to display the unordered list element that's a child of a list item being hovered over (which is a descendant of an unordered list which is a descendant of a nav element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this:

```
nav ul ul{
    display: none;
}
```

Uses the [display property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) to tell a `<ul>` element inside a `<ul>` and a `<nav>` element not to be displayed. Then this

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Means that when a `<li>` element inside a `<ul>` and `<nav>` is hovered over, it tells the  `<ul>` element, probably only the one inside, to be displayed as a block element.

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3UbA/)

Example of space separated CSS [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jn9GM/1/), and the use of `:hover` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryh4K/).

Hope this helps...

Comment: OMG, if I right understand, all "li" which inside "nav ul" will be visible when hovered... Thank you!

Comment: Pretty much - just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6670376/2943276) as well if it makes it any clearer - you might want to mark your question as answered if this helps enough.

Comment: See my answer for a link to the CSS3 WIKI on CSS Selectors and the use of the descendant combinator and direct descendant combinator.

Answer (score 1):

This all has to do with CSS Combinators.  You cna find information [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Selectors) on all CSS3 Selectors and Combinators.

The two combinators in question here are " " (or a space) and the ">" characters.  The [space] combinator is referred to as the descendant combinator.  The ">" symbol is referred to as the direct descendant combinator.

Given this selector... `nav ul li:hover > ul {}` you could verbosely say:  Apply these properties to a `UL` element that is directly descendant to *any* `LI` element which is being **hovered** that is descendant of *any* `UL` element that is descendant of *any* `NAV` element.

The above selector consequently applies to your 2.3.1 for example.

If you instead wrote:

```
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {}
```

Then your 2.3.1 LI would no longer become visible, as we are selecting specifically the second level of UL elements in the nav, and not any UL that is part of an LI.